# How to change a multiple repeated word in a document with vim

Tags: vim

I want to change a multiple occured word in a document by selecting and replacing.

For instance;

```
 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{{route('sliders.edit',$slider)}}">
                                            <i class="material-icons">edit</i> güncelle
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('sliders.destroy',$slider) }}">
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            @csrf
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                                <i class="material-icons">close</i> Sil
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
```

I want to change all "col-md-2" to "col-md-6" with selecting by one by. Also I do not want to use `:s/` command because of time considiration and complexity.

How can I do this with simple command?

Comment: `Also I do not want to use :s/ command because of time considiration and complexity.` explain it pls.

Comment: You can use a _mapping_ to build an incomplete `:substitute` command, with the search pattern pre-initialized and the cursor placed at the replacement part. That will save you a lot of typing. Vim is a toolbox with diverse capabilities; it's up to you to tweak it for your particular needs!

Answer (score 3):

How I would proceed:

1. Move to the first `div` and type `vat` to select the entire tag
2. Type `:substitute/col-md-\zs2/6/g`; note that when you type `:` you will see `:'<,'>`—this is expected, do not backspace those characters. (You can abbreviate to `:s/col-md-\zs2/6/g`

---

Without `:substitute`:

1. Type `/col-md-2` and hit Enter
2. Type `4` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> (we need « decrement » here because vim will think the number is negative)

Press `n.` until you’ve changed the ones you care about.

Another alternate: after (1) searching, do `cgn`, type the replacement text, and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Then you can use `.` to jump-and-change simultaneously.

Comment: Nice trick with <C-X> for this case! I may also suggest ci" motion and typing text you need. Like this - ci"col-md-6. Then do n to search next and . to repeat change. This will work for any text surrounded with double quotes. For others see :help motion.txt

Answer (score 1):

Using global command

```
:g/col-md2/execute "normal 4\<C-a>"
```

In the above solution you must use double quotes in order to use <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> -> `\<C-a>`.

Comment: Heh, nice adaptation of one of mine :) though you need `col-md-2` with two hyphens